# Does this linq query run on every iteration of the for-each loop?

Tags: linq, enumeration

In another question on SO I answered with code like the one below and got a comment that the LINQ-query probably was evaluated in every iteration of the for/each. Is that true?

I know that LINQ-querys does not executes before its items is evaluated so it seems possible that this way to iterate the result can make it run on every iteration?

```
Dim d = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()    
d.Add("Teststring", "Hello")    
d.Add("1TestString1", "World")    
d.Add("2TestString2", "Test")    

For Each i As String In From e In d Where e.Value.StartsWith("W") Select e.Key
    MsgBox("This key has a matching value:" & i)    
Next
```

Comment: Well it looks like what you had is OK, but at least format with end of line _ so it's not on one big line :)

Comment: Yeah. This late evaluation thing with LINQ will take a while to get familiar with.

Comment: Yeah it does.. but it's great once you get it, you can do some pretty sweet stuff.

Comment: Some cases are not so late with evaluation though... example, add a "order by" to my example below :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NO... in a foreach, the "GetEnumerator" is called only once (ever), and that is used going forward.

EDIT: I put a statement here about the result set being stored temporarily... that's only true for some cases... not this one, so I took it out.

EDIT: Please forgive this for being overly verbose... but I wanted to *show* you what is happening... so here's a Console app :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string item in MyCustomEnumerator()
                .Where(item => item.StartsWith("abc")))
            {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

        static IEnumerable<string> MyCustomEnumerator()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

            yield return "abc1";

            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

            yield return "abc2";

            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

            yield return "abc3";

            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

            yield return "xxx";
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: This will result in a DateTime, then abc1, then a DateTime, then abc2, then a DateTime, then abc3, then a DateTime.

Comment: Thanks. And pheuw. I used that way to iterate through LINQ results a lot in a recent project. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it will run the first time it is reached and produce an enumeration that has all the matching values.   What you will actually get back is an enumerator for that enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the FOR EACH...NEXT statement and it seems like Visual Basic evaluates the collection only once, before the loop begins, so it should not run the query on every iteration.

> Number of Iterations. Visual Basic
>   evaluates the collection only once,
>   before the loop begins. If your
>   statement block changes element or
>   group, these changes do not affect the
>   iteration of the loop.